# How to use Indian Currency Symbol in CRYSTAL REPORT 2008

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

[Only $ symbol Shown in Crystal Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL6f6.jpg)

I Need to use Indian Currency Symbol. So please Help me to do it.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Copy and paste the curreny symbol from Google

Comment: I tried it print like  Box

Comment: You need to update currency symbol in Windows..

Comment: Are you publish it report in BO repository

Comment: Text renderers use a glyph similar to ▯ for a character that the font doesn't supply a glyph for. This is a [font](https://www.quora.com/What-symbol-is-the-square-box-shown-for-non-representable-Unicode-characters) selection or installation problem. (We can't actually type the exact glyph since it's not a character.)